# mapping with spplot

Tags: raster, r, maps, visualisation, sp

This question should be easy!
I am using `spplot` for visualizing a map with suitable results. However, I would like to know how to set the limits of z, because the values are not being discriminated.

My data frame (df) is: long, lat, Z

```
spplot(df, "Z")
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: what does `range(df$Z)` say? Because it looks like you've got something in the region of 10^57 in there. Some kind of missing value code?

Answer (score 1):

Spacedman ist probably right but you could subset your dataframe before plotting like:

```
df <- df[df$Z < 300,]
spplot(df, "Z")
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks indeed like some sort of missing value (as suggested by @Spacedman). Anyway, as a straightforward alternative to subsetting your data (as suggested by @nebi), you could simply use the `zcol` argument inside `spplot` to display only a desired range of values. Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(raster)
rst <- raster(volcano)

## no 'zlim' specified
p1 <- spplot(rst)
## 'zlim' specified
p2 <- spplot(rst, zlim = c(100, 175))

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image: spplot]